# Cant access nested MovieClip AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, nested, flash-cs6

I'm trying to create a `intro screen` then a `start screen` after the intro screen is done playing.

I thought the easiest way of doing this would be on scene 1 frame 1, I would create a 
`MovieClip`.

By the way this is a separate document file. So I gave it a document class name of `mcStartGameScreen` and linked it to Flash Develop for actions.

Now the `MovieClip` that is on frame 1, I gave an instance name of `startMenu` then inside the `startMenu` MovieClip there is a MovieClip that I wanted the buttonMode enabled to be true. I add this MovieClip which is called `mcStart` on frame(65) inside my `startMenu`.

Now in my Actions I have this:

```
public class mcStartGameScreen extends MovieClip 
{

    private var mcStart:MovieClip;

    private var startMenu:MovieClip;

    public function mcStartGameScreen() 
    {
         startMenu.mcStart.buttonMode = true; //This is giving me the ERROR!

         mcStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startOnClick);          
    }

    private function startOnClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
         dispatchEvent(new Event("START_GAME"));
    }

    public function hideScreen():void
    {
         this.visible = false;  
    }

    public function showScreen():void
    {
         this.visible = true;
    }       
}
```

When I test the movie I get this 
`error: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a `MovieClip` with instance name `startMenu` placed on the stage, so no need for,

`private var startMenu:MovieClip;` you remove this from your code.

And always have the stage instance first and then proceed.

So modify your constructor like so:

```
public function mcStartGameScreen() 
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
}

private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
{
    startMenu.mcStart.buttonMode = true; //Now this will not give the ERROR!

    startMenu.mcStart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startOnClick);
}
```

Comment: But when I remove the private var startMenu:MovieClip; I get this new Error:    Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.  What could be going on?

Comment: Where is your 'startMenu`? In the library or on the stage.

Comment: my 'startMenu' Is on the stage. with the Instance name 'startMenu'. Its not linked to AS or anything

Comment: Are you using Flash Develop? If so then give linkage identifier in the library as `StartMenu` and create `var startMenu:StartMenu = new StartMenu(); addChild(startMenu);` in the constructor. Also remove it from the stage and position it using `startMenu.x` and `startMenu.y`

Comment: Yes I am. Awesome It seems to be working after like 5 more errors I had to fix haha. But one more thing please. How do I go about accessing the mcStart Movie CLip nested inside? Im getting errors trying to do the StartMenu.mcStart.buttonMode